# What is difference between max-age and max-stale in cache control mechanism

Tags: http, cache-control

I know this is a simple question, and I am sure that no body will mark this as duplicate question, because I have searched all over the SO. so my question is what is the difference between max-age and max-stale in Cache control mechanism of Http, I've read it in [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), but I felt its little complex, so if anybody can explain about this ? it would be great help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1):

> The "max-age" request directive indicates that the client is
> unwilling to accept a response whose age is greater than the
> specified number of seconds.  Unless the max-stale request directive
> is also present, the client is not willing to accept a stale
> response.

> ...

> The "max-stale" request directive indicates that the client is
> willing to accept a response that has exceeded its freshness
> lifetime.  If max-stale is assigned a value, then the client is
> willing to accept a response that has exceeded its freshness lifetime
> by no more than the specified number of seconds.

That is, `max-age` is the oldest that a response can be, *as long as* the `Cache-Control` from the origin server indicates that it is still fresh. `max-stale` indicates that, even if the response is known to be stale, you will also accept it as long as it's only stale by that number of seconds.

As per [Serving Stale Responses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.4):

> A cache SHOULD generate a Warning header field with the 110 warn-code
> (see Section 5.5.1) in stale responses.

So, if you specified `max-stale` and received a no-longer-fresh response, the `Warning` header would let you know.